# Share Texture coordinates between geometry node objects

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders

I have two objects, one object is a lofted mesh over some curves using geometry nodes and another is a subdivided circle. I wish them to share the same texture coordinates so I can blend them seamlessly even though they are separate meshes. The catch is they must be separate so I can use them in separate render passes. I have a blend file [image]

Here is my attempt so far. [image]

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a tricky one, I'm not sure if you can quite like *that*, but one way of doing it is to use the object coordinates.
Set it to an empty somewhere in your scene, and then project the texture onto both objects like this: [image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yep that did the trick! Thankyou!